# keyerror index in facetgrid

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have this df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.array([1,2,3]),
                   'A': np.array([10, np.nan,30]),
                   'B': np.array([100, np.nan, np.nan])})
```

I am counting nan

```
df_nan = df.isna().groupby(['x'], sort=False).sum().reset_index()
df_nan.drop('x', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Plot

```
sns.FacetGrid(df_nan.T, row=str(df_nan.columns), col=(df_nan.values),
              palette="Set3", height=4, aspect=2)
```

I am keep receiving : `KeyError: "Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of how you want your plot to look like, but this error is caused by different things.

First, you are passing a transposed dataframe `df_nan.T` to `FacetGrid`, which makes your original columns `['A', 'B']` to become row indexes. So Seaborn will throw a `KeyError` because it won't be able to find `'A'` and `'B1'` in the columns anymore.

Second, the `row` parameter should be a single string, ideally the name of a categorical column. This will order `FacetGrid` to prepare as many columns as the number of possible values in that column. So passing a list with more than one element will throw an error as well. Also, your error is thrown because you are passing the columns index to the `str` function, and then to the `FacetGrid`, which will make seaborn to look for a column named `"Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')"` that doesn't exist, so the `KeyError`.

I guess you want to plot the number of `nan` values in each column, so this is a way to do it. You first need to melt your `df_nan` in order to get a categorical column:

```
df_nan = df_nan.melt(var_name='Original Column', value_name='Nan Count')
```

Which gives us:

```
  Original Column  Nan Count
0               A          1
1               B          2
```

The you call `sns.catplot` (categorical plot) as follows:

```
sns.catplot(data=df_nan, 
            kind='bar', 
            y='Nan Count', 
            x='Original Column', 
            palette="Set3", 
            height=4, 
            aspect=2)
```

And this will give you the following plot:

[image]

I hope this is what you wanted. If not, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the input for the parameters `row` and `column` are supposed to be `str` (check [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)), and you're trying to cast the columns of the dataframe directly.

Basically, when you're doing `str(df_nan.columns)`, you are literally getting the string `"Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')"`.

Can you please explain a little bit about what are you trying to accomplish or look at with the plot? That will simplify the path to the answer.